# Ruby one liner to replace only lines that match, discard others

Tags: ruby, regex

Looking for the ruby one liner substitute to print out a substitution only if the line matches the regular expression:

`echo -e "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3" | perl -ne "print if s/Line 2/Line 2 replaced, others discarded/g"`

Input:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

Output:

```
Line 2 replaced, others discarded
```

Comment: `string.scan(/^line 2$/).map {|x| x.gsub(/2/, "2 replaced, others discarded") }.join("\n")`

Comment: Should `Line 2` equal the whole line? Your Perl example does not  check for the start/end of line positions. What is rthe expected output for `"Line 1\nLine 2 Line 2\nLine 3 Line 2"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I do not care about start/end of line.  It is just an example.  I am just looking for the recipe in Ruby.  The regular expression itself is not important.  Thank you for your concern though.

Comment: Anybody care to explain the down votes?  I believe my question is legit; I find a lot of examples to replace 'perl -pe' with ruby, but none for this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I know, there is no equivalent to `-ne` shorthand in ruby. So it will be little longer:

```
echo -e "Line 1\nLine 2\nLine 3" | ruby -e 'puts $<.read.lines.map {|l| l =~ /Line 2/ ? l.gsub(/Line 2/, "Line 2 replaced, others discarded") : nil }.compact'
```

Where:

- `$<` also `ARGF` ([docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ARGF.html)) is Stream for file argument or STDIO
- `$<.read` will read it all to string
- `$<.read.lines` split by new line character, returns array
- `map {|l| ... }` will collect result of expression in a block to new array
- `l =~ /Line 2/` check if string match Regex
- `l.gsub(/Line 2/, "Line 2 replaced")` will replace all "Line 2" to "Line 2 replaced"
- `.compact` will remove `nil` values from array (return new array without nil's)
- `puts []` will print each element of array on new line

Probably ruby is not a best chose for this task, I would choose `sed` or do it in text editor. Most of text editors can find and replace by regex nowdays

Comment: I accept you answer because it fits the bill. I can now replace my perl one liner with ruby, since perl has problems handling multibyte unicode characters. Ruby and Python has none of these problems, but are missing the practical "-ne" feature. I suspected that no "-ne" exist, because I searched the web to no vail, but I am glad you confirmed me this and still showed me a simple, one liner solution. And please, up vote my question if you feel it was worth it, to counteract those who down voted it (what is the problem with my question???)